# searchfiltering across selections with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, select

I can't seem to figure out the right way to make a searchfiltering function that will push (correct word?) an expanded WHERE statement to a SELECT query.

I have this piece of code that displays a list of adverts:

```
    $where = isset($catid) ? ' AND ad.category = '.$catid.'' : '';

   $row = $db->dbh->query('SELECT ad.*, 
   (SELECT img.image FROM '.$config->db_prefix.'_images AS img 
   WHERE img.aid = ad.aid LIMIT 1) AS img 
   FROM '.$config->db_prefix.'_adverts ad 
   WHERE ad.approved = 1 '.$where.'');
```

Let's say that I want to view all ads in a specific category f.x. TV (id 5) and then in that category I want to display all ads within a given price range (100 - 800). 
I am not sure how I can expand my WHERE statement to handle this and how I should do it from my HTML.
Hope my question is understandable.

My DB structure in the adverts table is this:

```
aid             int(11)     
fid             int(11)
ad_type         int(11)
title           varchar(255)
text            tinytext
price           decimal(10,2) 
category        int(11)
friends_allow   int(11)
cr_date         int(11)         
expiry_date     int(11)
approved        int(1)
ip              varchar(255)
email           varchar(255) 
zip_for_pickup  int(11) 
views           int(11)
```

SOLUTION

```
$filters = array();

if(!empty($post_fields['cat']) && $post_fields["cat"] != "all") {
        $category = $post_fields['cat'];
        $filters[] = '(category = ' . $category .')';
    }

if(!empty($post_fields['search_field'])) {
    $title_and_text = $post_fields['search_field'];
    $filters[] = '(title LIKE "%' . $title_and_text  .'%" OR text LIKE "%' . $title_and_text .'%")';
}

if(!empty($post_fields['price_min_field'])) {
    if(!empty($post_fields['price_max_field'])) {
        $filters[] = '(price >= '. $post_fields['price_min_field'].' AND price <= '. $post_fields['price_max_field'] .')';
    } else {
        $filters[] = '(price >= '. $post_fields['price_min_field'].')';
    }      
}

if(!empty($post_fields['distance'])) {
    $adverts = new Adverts();
    $filters[] = '('. $adverts->find_geo_location($post_fields["userzip"], $post_fields["distance"]) .')';
}

$filter =  implode(' AND ', $filters);
```

Comment: And you want us to just guess at the structure of your database?

Comment: Sorry about that! Question is updated with the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN HTML place 2 dropdowns Price From and Price To.
Get the selected value in the PHP side . Based on that use concatenation. Replace 100 and 800 withe selected value.

```
 $where = isset($catid) ? ' AND ad.category = '.$catid.'' : '';

 if ($pricefilter) {
   $where .= 'AND ad.price>100 AND ad.price < 800';
 }
```

Comment: What if I use the searchbox and find a list of results with 
`text LIKE "%'. $search_string .'%" OR title LIKE "%'. $search_string .'%"` and then in that result again wants to filter with a pricerange - that is my problem

Comment: What ever it may you have to modify your query at certain point. You have to persist the previously selected option. You have to plan the '$where' part according to the filter selection.